# how to get the value from disabled box in selenium testng framework?

Tags: selenium, testng

how to get the data from disabled textfield or nonedited box?i need to get the data from non edited box.For example, pagelength is 2, i need to read the data, but we cant change the data from the textfield.i need to read, and print it as 2  in testng

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please revise your question and write with more clear things. At this stage it does not provide clear that what actually you want to perform using selenium. Also you have not specified that you are using selenium IDE or Web driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from disabled text field as we do fetch value from general text field.
store the text field in webelement and call a method getAttribute("value");

> //value is one of the attribute associated with text field.

Here is working example:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_disabled.asp");
        String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main']/div[2]/div[2]/input")).getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println("Disabled Test Field contains: "+value);
```

*O/p would be-  Disabled Test Field conatins: Hello World!*